# On $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n/a_n$ where $\exp(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n z^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, power-series

Suppose that $(a_n)_{n>0}$ is a decreasing sequence of positive real numbers, the radius of convergence of $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n$ is equal to $1$, and $f(1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges. Let $e^{f(z)}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n z^n$ (it's easy to see that $b_n$ are positive, and the radius of convergence of this series is also equal to $1$).

> Does $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n/a_n$ necessarily exist under these conditions?

At first sight this looks too good to be true, but I can't find a counterexample, no matter what I try.

The motivation is [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3449610), where I'm working with $f(z)=\operatorname{Li}_2(z)$ (i.e. $a_n=1/n^2$). The computation of $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2 b_n$, as seen there, would be much easier if the existence is established; without it, I (seem to) have to go a very tedious way.

---

**Update.** The answer by @reuns indeed gives a counterexample (even a series of).

Simplified a bit, let $a_n=4^{-k}$ for $2^k\leqslant n<2^{k+1}$ for each $k\geqslant 0$; then $$f(z)=\frac{w(z)}{1-z},\quad w(z)=z-3\sum_{k=1}^\infty 4^{-k}z^{2^k}$$ and then $g(z)=e^{f(z)}$ satisfies $$(1-z)^2 g'(z)=\big(w(z)+(1-z)w'(z)\big)g(z),$$ which, after substituting $g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n z^n$, gives (for $n>1$) $$(n+1)b_{n+1}+(n-1)b_{n-1}-2nb_n=b_n+3\sum_{\substack{k>0\\2^k\leqslant n}}(2^{-k}-4^{-k})b_{n-2^k}-3\sum_{\substack{k>0\\2^k\leqslant n+1}}2^{-k}b_{n-2^k+1}.$$

Now, if $L:=\lim_{n\to\infty}(b_n/a_n)$ exists, then $L=L_d:=\lim_{m\to\infty}(b_{2^m+d}/a_{2^m+d})$ for each $d\in\mathbb{Z}$. But the preceding equality (at $n=2^m+d$, multiplied by $2^m$, with $m\to\infty$ taken) implies $$L_0+4L_{-2}-8L_{-1}=-3,\quad L_1+4L_{-1}-2L_0=0,\quad\text{etc.}$$

*The same way, the existence of $L_{-1}$ implies $L_d=L_{-1}$ for $d<0$, and the values of $L_d$ for $d\geqslant 0$ can be computed just like above. Numerical experiments show that actually $L_{-1}=g(1)=e^2$.*

I didn't prove the latter yet, and didn't consider generalisations ($2^k$ replaced by $c_k$ with increasing $c_{k+1}-c_k$, etc.) as well; I think these questions deserve to be dedicated follow-ups.

Comment: In $Li_2(z)$ we have $a_n-a_{n+1}$ decreasing too so it has more chances to be true.

Comment: It reminds me of this paper by Erdős et al.: https://old.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1949-01.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with $a_n$ constant $=2^{-k}$ on intervals of length $\lfloor 2^k/k^2\rfloor$ so that $$\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n = \sum_{k\ge 1} 2^{-k} \lfloor 2^k/k^2\rfloor$$

It has many "divide by $2$" jumps and those are smoothed in $b$ causing $a/b$ to have oscillations at the jumps of $a$. You are better qualified than me to turn this into a proof, so I'll just give a numerical check

[image]